# PowerShell RegEx to split MAC address

Tags: regex, powershell, mac-address, capture-group

I need to verify MAC address in RAW format using RegEx and split it into an array of 6 values by 2 characters. 
When I use following pattern, I get content of last iteration of capture group only:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> "708BCDBC8A0D" -match "^([0-9a-z]{2}){6}$"
True
PS C:\Windows\System32> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              0D
0                              708BCDBC8A0D


PS C:\Windows\System32>
```

With what pattern can I caputere all the groups? 
I need this result:

```
0 = 708BCDBC8A0D
1 = 70
2 = 8B
3 = CD
4 = BC
5 = 8A
6 = 0D
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input HEX as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372483/input-hex-as-a-string)

Comment: `[System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress]::Parse('708BCDBC8A0D').GetAddressBytes() |% ToString X2`

Comment: Looks like @iRon's link answers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not capture multiple groups with single group definition.
Avoid using RegEx when unnecessary as it takes lots of CPU. Valuable for millions of recrds.

For MACs you can use special `PhysicalAddress` class:

```
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress]::Parse('708BCDBC8A0D')
```

For .Net 5 (Powershell Core ***I think*** based on it) there is `TryParse` method added, but in .Net 4.5 there is no `TryParse` method.

To check .Net framework powershell running use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetExecutingAssembly().ImageRuntimeVersion`

---

```
'708BCDBC8A0D' -match "^$('([A-F0-9]{2})' * 6)$"; $Matches
'708BCDBC8A0D' -match '^([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})$'; $Matches
```

---

```
'@(0..5) | ForEach-Object {'708BCDBC8A0D'.Substring($_ * 2, 2)}'
```

---

```
@(
    [String]::new('708BCDBC8A0D'[0..1]),
    [String]::new('708BCDBC8A0D'[2..3]),
    [String]::new('708BCDBC8A0D'[4..5]),
    [String]::new('708BCDBC8A0D'[6..7]),
    [String]::new('708BCDBC8A0D'[8..9]),
    [String]::new('708BCDBC8A0D'[10..11])
)
```

Comment: I am aware about higher CPU load when using RegEx, but I need it for validating MAC address anyway. 
"Hack" with `* 6` is good not to repeat definition.
And this PowerShell way `@(0..5) | ForEach-Object {'708BCDBC8A0D'.Substring($_ * 2, 2)}` too. 
Thanks for hints!

Comment: Maybe using `[System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress]::Parse('708BCDBC8A0D')` is better in your case ?

Comment: As for the .NET versions underlying PowerShell versions: as of the current stable version, PowerShell 7.1.3, it is .NET 5.0.4. v7.2 will likely be based on .NET 6.0 (not released yet). You can run the following command in a PowerShell (Core) session to determine the underlying .NET version(s): `(ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content -Raw  "$PSHOME/pwsh.runtimeconfig.json")).runtimeOptions.includedFrameworks.version`

Answer (score 0):

As you've observed, the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), which reflects the result of the most recent (scalar-input<sup>[1]</sup>) [regular-expression-based `match` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), only ever contains the *last* instance of what an embedded *capture group* (`(...)`) captured.

Generally, `-match` only ever looks for *at most ONE* match in the input.

- [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing a new `-matchall` operator that would find *all* matches and return them as an *array*.

*Direct* use of the `[regex]` class ([`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex)) that underlies PowerShell's regex functionality already provides that ability, namely in the form of the [`::Matches()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches), in which case capture groups aren't even needed.

```
# Note: Inline option (?i) makes the regex case-INsensitive
#       (which PowerShell's operators are BY DEFAULT).
PS> [regex]::Matches('708BCDBC8A0D', '(?i)[0-9a-f]{2}').Value
70
8B
CD
BC
8A
0D
```

However, with a bit of trickery, you can also use `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```
# Note: No inline option needed: -split - like -match and -replace -
#       is case-INsensitive by default.
PS> '708BCDBC8A0D' -split '([0-9a-f]{2})' -ne ''
70
8B
CD
BC
8A
0D
```

If can assume that *all* character pairs in the input strings are hex byte values, you can simplify to:

```
'708BCDBC8A0D' -split '(..)' -ne ''
```

Note:

- The regex is of necessity enclosed in `(...)`, a capturing group, to explicitly instruct `-split` to include what it matches in the results; since the regex normally describes the *separators* between the substrings of interest, its matches are normally *not* included.
- In this case it is *only* the "separators" we care about, whereas the substrings *between* them are *empty strings* here, so we filter them out with `-ne ''`.

---

<sup>[1] If the LHS of a `-match` operation is an *array* (a collection), matching occurs against *each element*, and the sub-array of matching elements (rather than a single Boolean) is returned. In this case, `$Matches` is *not* populated.</sup>

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, @Jeremy - answer updated.